# How to connect vue.js with gapi

Tags: vue.js, google-api-js-client

I have been trying too many things and I am not be able to fix this problem. I'm trying to connect vue.js with gapi in order to use Google Spreadsheet after that.
The problem is that I think the api.js in the script is not loading I don't know the reason. Everytime the console says: 'gapi is not defined', I tried to put a setTimeout in the gapi.load and nothing.
If someone can help me..

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<script>
    import * as http from "http";
    import Vue from "vue";

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                entries: []
            };
        },
        mounted() { 

             // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
      var CLIENT_ID = 'AIzaSyBcN4pjE5yK9ZXphpfe7yJddrvYTxCUhYU';

      // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
      var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/sheets/v4/rest"];

      // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
      // included, separated by spaces.
      var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly";

        const gauthOption = {
        discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES
        };

         gapi.load('client:auth2', gauthOption);
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to wait for gapi before executing the code you can use onload query parameter in script tag, like below:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoadCallback"  async defer></script>
<script>
window.onLoadCallback = function(){
  gapi.load('client:auth2', gauthOption);
}
```

Comment: As I wrote in the first post, I tried to use the 'setTimeout' and didn´t work, and also I tried the onload query parameter..It is like the script never loads (the ones on https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js)

Comment: @MrSer - did you find any solution for this ?